# Troubleshooting 'Method not annotated with HTTP method type' error in Java Spring @FeignClient interface

Tags: java, spring, http, interface, feign

I have created the following interface in Java, using the Spring annotations @FeignClient and @GetMapping:

```
@FeignClient(name = "serviceTechnicalTest", url = "${endpoints.url-technicalTest}" , configuration = FeignRetryConfiguration.class)
public interface URLTechnicalTestFeign {
    @GetMapping
    UrlCandidateResponse getUrlCandidateTechnicalTest(@RequestBody UrlCandidateRequest urlCandidateRequest);
}
```

When I run the bootRun in gradle I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.pragma.talento.trackingdashboardapi.infraestructure.feing.URLTechnicalTestFeign]: Factory method 'uRLTechnicalTestFeign' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method URLTechnicalTestFeign#getUrlCandidateTechnicalTest() not annotated with HTTP method type (ex. GET, POST)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method URLTechnicalTestFeign#getUrlCandidateTechnicalTest() not annotated with HTTP method type (ex. GET, POST)
```

How can I solve this error?

I have tried to change the url, even I reviewed if there was an issue in the feign impxlementation in gradle. The following is the implementation of the function:

```
candidateRequest.setTestId(test.getTestId());

String dynamicUrl = test.getTypeTest().getTestURL();
URLTechnicalTestFeign dynamicUrlTechnicalTestFeign = urlTechnicalTestClientFeignFactory.createClient(dynamicUrl);

urlCandidateResponse = dynamicUrlTechnicalTestFeign.getUrlCandidateTechnicalTest(candidateRequest);
```